# ¿Es igual "import XXX" que "from XXX import a, b, c"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Yo entendia que

```
import XXX
print(XXX.a)
```

y

```
from XXX import a, b, c
print(a)
```

eran lo mismo, y elegir uno y otro era cuestión de preferencias personales.

El caso es que tengo este módulo `servicio.py` que contiene la maqueta de un servicio que lee algún dato y lo mantiene en la variable `var`.

Cada vez que se llama al servicio, `var` debería actualizarse, lo que simulo sumandole 100 en cada pasada.

*servicio.py*

```
var = 1

def cambia():
    global var
    var += 100
    print(f"cambia var = {var}")
```

Desde otro módulo quiero llamar al servicio y luego recuperar el valor accesando directamente la variable `var`.

**Alternativa 1**

```
import servicio

print(id(servicio.var), servicio.var)
servicio.cambia()
print(id(servicio.var), servicio.var)
```

que produce:

```
9788992 1
cambia var = 101
9792192 101
```

**Alternativa 2**

```
from servicio import var, cambia

print(id(var), var)
cambia()
print(id(var), var)
```

que produce:

```
9788992 1
cambia var = 101
9788992 1
```

¿Alguien me puede explicar la diferencia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como ya has descubierto "por las malas" esas sintaxis de `import` no son equivalentes. Pero ¿cuál es la diferencia exactamente?

```
import servicio
```

lo que hace es cargar el fichero `servicio.py` en memoria, ejecutarlo, y crear **en el espacio de nombres local** el símbolo `servicio`, que actúa como si fuera una objeto, en el sentido de que admite la sintaxis "punto" para acceder a sus símbolos internos, de modo que puedes poner `servicio.var`, `servicio.cambia`, etc. Todos los símbolos que `servicio.py` defina a nivel `global()` (global opera a nivel de módulo), son accesibles desde el código que lo importa a través de la notación "punto".

En cambio cuando haces

```
from servicio import var
```

lo que ocurre es que, igual que antes, se carga `servicio.py` en memoria, se ejecuta, y se crea **en el espacio de nombres local** el símbolo `var`.

Simplificando mucho, es como si se hubiera hecho:

```
import servicio
var = servicio.var
del servicio         # Esto borra el símbolo
```

Por tanto tenemos ahora dos símbolos `var` diferentes, con diferente visibilidad:

1. El símbolo `var` que aparece listado si haces `globals()` dentro de `servicio.py` y que se creó como consecuencia de la línea `var=1` en ese fichero.
2. El símbolo `var` que aparece listado si haces `globals()` dentro de `main.py`, y que se creó como consecuencia del `from servicio import var`. Este comienza inicializado con el valor 1. Supongo que no te extrañará mucho descubrir que si hiciéramos `var = 2` en `main.py` eso sólo cambiará el valor del símbolo local, sin afectar al símbolo descrito en el punto 1.

Cuando la función `cambia()` hace `var+=100`, está cambiando en realidad el valor del símbolo 1 de los dos antes explicados. El valor del símbolo 2 no es afectado, pues está en otro espacio de nombres.

Cuando haces el `import servicio` no ves estos efectos secundarios porque siempre estás refiriendo al símbolo 1, al tener que usar la sintaxis `servicio.valor`.

**Nota**: Mirar los `id()` de las variables no ayuda mucho aqui, y más bien resulta confuso, porque en el fondo `id()` lo que te devuelve es una especie de hash del valor que contiene. En realidad devuelve la dirección de memoria donde está el dato correspondiente, pero **no la dirección de la variable**, que es seguramente lo que tú querías averiguar. No hay forma de obtener la dirección de la variable en python, y la dirección del dato no ayuda porque obviamente cambia si cambias el valor de la variable.

Comment: Es "la deformación C". Siempre estoy pensando en punteros, no en referencias. Con punteros todo está siempre actualizado.

Comment: Puedes seguir pensando en punteros, creo que es la analogía más correcta en cuanto a lo que significa `a = b` (se asignan los punteros). Pero tienes que cambiar tu pensamiento en cuanto a lo que significa `a = 1`, ya que no equivaldría a `*a=1`, sino a `a = new Integer(1)` (suponiendo que C tuviera un operador `new`, cambialo por un `malloc()` si prefieres). Así que cuando tu `cambiar()` hace `var += 100`, no está haciendo `*var += 100`, sino `var = new Integer(*var + 100)`. Por otro lado el `var` de main se inicializa como `var = servidor.var`, una asignación de punteros "normal".

Answer (score 3):

No es exactamente igual. La diferencia entre `from a import b` e `import a` (o incluso `import a.b`) radica en qué es lo que hace a nivel referencias.

`import a` lo que hace es importar el módulo `a` y crear una referencia en el namespace actual

`from a import b` importa el módulo `a` y crea una referencia a `b`

Qué es lo que ocurre cuando hacemos `from a import b, c`?

El intérprete importa `a` y crea dos referencias diferentes a `b` y a `c`, generando situaciones como las que describes.

Aunque sean objetos del mismo módulo están referenciados por separado.

Answer (score 0):

Simbólicamente, lo que estás haciendo en la `alternativa 1` corresponde a heredar las características de un "nodo padre" llamémosle `PadreA` (un objeto de clase)... Cuando posteriormente usas:

```py
print(id(servicio.var), servicio.var)
servicio.cambia()
print(id(servicio.var), servicio.var)
```

Desde los "nodos" estarías haciendo algo como:

```
método(PadreA.child1)
método(PadreA.child2)
método(PadreA.child1)
```

Nótese que si `PadreA` almacenase algún tipo de memoria tal que cambie con cada ejecución, como un contador (al final menciono que es más probable en este caso), sería distinto que la segunda alternativa:

```
método(PadreA.child1)
método(PadreB.child2)
método(PadreA.child1)
```

Porque estarías llamando solo dos veces el nodo padreA y no tres veces.

---

Otra diferencia como menciona @abulafia es que con la primera alternativa estás heredando todos los métodos de la clase... entonces `PadreA` tendría `N` hijos, siendo N la cantidad de métodos del modulo.

En cambio, la alternativa dos; `PadreB` solo tendría el hijo directo del método que invocaste. Solo tendría `1` método (no `N` como en la primera alternativa).

***Aclaración:** Estas son conclusiones que he sacado del uso personal de clases y módulos, no tengo pruebas pero creo que tiene mucho sentido.

---

Entre otras cosas, siendo redundante, probando con `servicio.py` como:

```
import random

random.seed(0)
var=random.randint(1,100)
    
def cambia():
    global var

    var=random.randint(1,100)
    print(f"cambia var = {var}")
```

Se replica la salida, utilizando un debugger se comprueban los objetos en memoria (alternativa 1):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual contiene una sola instancia de un objeto, de la misma instancia se llaman dos métodos distintos.

y alternativa 2:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### En resumen:

- La alternativa 1 utiliza dos características (una variable y un método) de una misma instancia.
- La alternativa 2 usas dos instancias distintas de una misma clase para lo mismo.

*Lo que en realidad sucede es que la alternativa 2 al ejecutar en instancias distintas, no tienen relación, y es incapaz de modificar la variable `var`, resulta teniendo el mismo `id` ya que no ha cambiado