# Variable importada no se actualiza

Tags: python, python-import

Tengo un módulo `param.py` que contiene los parámetros de la aplicación más funciones de apoyo. Este módulo es importado por el resto de la aplicación. Eventualmente algunos parámetros pueden ser cambiados durante la ejecución.

El problema es que cuando importo los parámetros desde otros módulos, los valores "quedan fijos", y cuando trato de modificarlos, se cambian en algunos módulos y en otros no.

Reduje el problema a un sólo parámetro para demostrarlo. El parámetro es el mensaje de bienvenida, que se puede cambiar por otro usando `set_msg`.

**param.py**

```
mensaje = "Hello, World!"

def set_msg(msg):
    global mensaje
    mensaje = msg
    
def print_msg():
    global mensaje # Redundante
    print(mensaje)
```

Este módulo se ocupa en todos los demás, como en `main.py`:

**main.py**

```
from param import mensaje, set_msg, print_msg

print("Mensaje original: ", mensaje)
set_msg("Hola, Mundo")
print("Mensaje cambiado: ", mensaje)
print("print_msg(): ", end="")
print_msg()
```

Esto produce como resultado

```
Mensaje original:  Hello, World!
Mensaje cambiado:  Hello, World!
print_msg(): Hola, Mundo
```

cuando lo que espero es

```
Mensaje original:  Hello, World!
Mensaje cambiado:  Hola, Mundo
print_msg(): Hola, Mundo
```

He seguido la ejecución con el depurador, paso a paso, y la variable `mensaje` realmente se actualiza dentro del módulo `param.py`.

¿Alguien me explica que está pasando?

Comment: Esta pregunta me sonaba que ya la había respondido yo... y resulta que ya la habías preguntado tú :-) aqui -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/510310/7123 y esta fue mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/510311/7123

Comment: ah, y para escribir algo mas corto que `param.variable` lo unico que se me ocurre es `import param as p` para así poder usar `p.variable`

Answer (score 1):

#### explicación

Cuando haces algo como `from param import mensaje`, el código actua similar a lo siguente:

```
import param
mensaje = param.mensaje
del param
```

Si bien ambas variables referencian al mismo objeto, siguen siendo variables distintas.

Cuando haces `param.mensaje = "nuevo mundo"`, en realidad, estas cambiando a que hace referencia la variable mensaje en param. Pero ese cambio solo ocurre allí, en param.
Mientras tanto, la variable mensaje de main.py sigue referenciando a la cadena anterior.

En resumen `message is param.message` da False.

#### Aclaraciones de conceptos

Piensa en las variables como "nombres" que les das a los objetos. Eso te ayudará a entender.

En Python, no se guarda en una variable el camino que se hace para llegar a un objeto. En su lugar, se guarda el resultado de hacer ese camino.
Eso significa, cuando haces `hola = a.b`, python guarda el valor de a.b, pero cuando vuelvas a acceder a la variable hola, no se vuelve a obtener el atributo b, si no que obtienes el valor que **tenía** b cuando se asignó el valor.

#### mutabilidad

Pero, luego puede surgir algo confuso. Y es que si reemplazaras la cadena por una lista y aplicas el método append, ambas variables reflejan el cambio.
Este "extraño" comportamiento, se debe a que en todo el tiempo de ejecución las dos variables referencian a la misma lista. Y esa lista está siendo modificada in-place.

Los objetos que se pueden modificar in-place se llaman "mutables".

Veras que, nuevamente, si asignas una lista a param.message el cambio no se refleja. Por que nuevamente las variables referencian a objetos distintos. Uno la lista original, y el otro a la nueva.

#### se puede evitar tener que hacer modulo.variable?

La respuesta depende de con que estas trabajando. Si es con objetos mutables, y no tenes necesidad de hacer ningúna asignación a ninguna de las dos variables, la respuesta es si.

Si estas trabajando con objetos inmutables, la respuesta es no. Ya que para "cambiarlos" en realidad necesitas crear un nuevo objeto, implicita o explicitamente.

Con este ultimo escenario, se puede hacer algo muy rebuscado, que es envolver el objeto inmutable en un objeto mutable e implementar todos los métodos necesarios a usar para ahorrarse sintaxis. En tu ejemplo, el objeto mutable debería devolver la cadena que envuelve en el método magico str.

La verdad, es muy rebuscado, pero hay cosas que se acercan a lo que buscas.

#### formas de importación

Si queres escribir lo menos posible, podes usar `as`, que le indica a Python el nombre de la variable donde guardar el módulo. Y en ese escenario podes usar una sola letra por ejemplo

```
import params as p
```

O, incluso, podes aplicar `from paquete import modulo`

```
from paquete.subpackete import modulo
```

Estas utilidades en los imports hacen que, generalmente, hacer modulo.variable no sea algo molesto.

Estos trucos se hacen mucho, por ejemplo, al importar tkinter y ttk:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se importa una variable en python de otro módulo, no se importa la variable, sino una copia de su valor. Así que tienes dos variables mensaje, una dentro de param.py y otro distinta pero con el mismo nombre en main.py. Esta última se inicializa en el momento de importarla con el valor que tenga param.py

Como solución, o bien pones una función get_msg(), o bien puedes importar de esta forma

```
import param

print(param.mensaje)  # Aquí si tienes una referencia a la variable de param
```

Se bueno.

Comment: Preferiría escribir algo más corto que `param.mensaje` (el caso real es más largo). ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Son _scopes_ diferentes, necesitarás siempre _"cualificar"_ la variable con el módulo o el objeto que la contiene.

Comment: Copiar no es la palabra correcta, ya que en realidad, el valor no se copia