# ¿Por qué cuando creo una variable asignándole una instancia estas comparten los atributos?

Tags: python

Me estaba practicando con clases e instancias en Python, y me encontré con que al asignar una instancia a una variable, estas trabajan como si la variable fuese un apuntador, justo como en lenguaje C. Es decir, cuando hago un cambio de los atributos de la variable o de la instancia, el cambio ocurre en ambas, como si fuesen la misma instancia pero con distintos nombres. No entiendo por qué funciona de esta forma, y no me parece haber visto algo parecido en la documentación de Python.

```
class Carro(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.marca = None

primer_carro = Carro()
primer_carro.marca = "Honda"
   
otro = primer_carro
otro.marca = "Subaru"

print(otro.marca) #imprime Subaru
print(primer_carro.marca) #Tambien imprime Subaru, en lugar de Honda
```

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: No estás creando "otra" instancia, estás creando una **copia** de la misma instanacia. Si deseas crear otra instancia, debes usar `otro = Carro()`.

Comment: @ElTroll ni siquiera es una copia de la misma instancia. Es "la misma instancia pero con otro nombre".

Comment: Perdona si mi respuesta suena incorrecta. Si puedo responder otra pregunta, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: En la documentación de Python se especifica que una asignación (`otro = primer_carro`) enlaza un nombre a un objeto: [Vinculación de nombres](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En una sentencia de asignación como:

```
primer_carro = Carro()
```

lo que estas pidiendo es que al nombre `primer_carro` se le vincule con el objeto resultante de evaluar la expresión de la parte derecha. En este caso, se vincula `primer_carro` con un objeto de la clase `Carro` recién instanciado.

Lo mismo ocurre con `otro = primer_carro`, solo que el resultado de evaluar la expresión de la parte derecha es simplemente una referencia al objeto al que esta vinculada la variable `primer_carro`, por lo que otro queda vinculada también al mismo objeto en memoria.

Nada se copia, simplemente creamos otro nombre para poder hacer referencia al mismo objeto. Para forzar a que Python copie un objeto hay que decírselo explícitamente, es decir, al asignar la expresión del lado derecho tiene que generar una copia del objeto.

Si queremos por tanto crear una nueva variable y asignarle a esta una copia de un objeto existente, deberemos primero crear la copia y luego asociar la variable a dicha instancia. En tu caso, o bien creas un nuevo objeto:

```
otro = Carro()
otro.marca = "Subaru"
```

o puedes usar el modulo [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html), como en este caso el atributo `marca` es un objeto inmutable (`str`) basta con crear una copia superficial con `copy.copy`:

```
import copy

class Carro(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.marca = None

primer_carro = Carro()
primer_carro.marca = "Honda"

otro = copy.copy(primer_carro)
otro.marca = "Subaru"
```

Al crear una copia superficial, si ocurriría lo que crees que ocurría en tu código, se crea una copia de la instancia pero no de los objetos que forman sus atributos, si estos son mutables eso puede ser un problema:

```
import copy

class Carro(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.datos = {"Marca": None, "Modelo": None}
         
nuevo_carro = Carro()
nuevo_carro.datos["Marca"] = "Honda"
print(nuevo_carro.datos) # {'Marca': 'Honda', 'Modelo': None}

otro = copy.copy(nuevo_carro)
otro.datos["Marca"] = "Subaru"
print(nuevo_carro.datos) # {'Marca': 'Subaru', 'Modelo': None}
```

Aquí necesitamos una copia profunda si no queremos que pase lo anterior:

```
nuevo_carro = Carro()
nuevo_carro.datos["Marca"] = "Honda"
otro = copy.deepcopy(nuevo_carro)
otro.datos["Marca"] = "Subaru"
print(nuevo_carro.datos) # {'Marca': 'Honda', 'Modelo': None}
print(otro.datos) # {'Marca': 'Subaru', 'Modelo': None}
```

siempre puedes implementar los métodos `__copy__` y `__deepcopy__` en tu clase para personalizar como se realizan estas operaciones y ajustarlos a las características concretas de tu clase.

A continuación una explicación "algo" mas larga...

---

### Todo es un objeto

Creo que lo primero que hay que entender es que todo en Pyhon es un objeto almacenado en memoria, desde un entero, `None`, una función o un modulo importado, todo son objetos con una identidad única durante todo su tiempo de vida. Esta "identidad" es retornada por el built-in `id()` y es, en el caso de CPython, la dirección de memoria donde esta alojado el objeto.

### Identificadores o nombres en Python

Tener todo como objetos en memoria esta muy bien, pero para poder hacer algo con esos objetos necesitamos una forma amena para humanos que permita acceder a ellos, llamar a sus métodos, etc. Es aquí donde entran en escena los nombres o identificadores, que hacen **referencia siempre a algún objeto en memoria**. Creamos nombres siempre vinculándolos a un objeto en operaciones como la definición de clases o funciones (donde el nombre de la función/clase se asocia al objeto `function`/`class` creado en memoria), las expresiones de asignación como en tu ejemplo, en los imports o los encabezados de los ciclos `for`.

Un mismo objeto puede tener varios identificadores asociados a el, puedes saber si dos variables están asociadas al mismo objeto usando el [operador de identidad `is`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/343143/15089).

### Python y sus implementaciones

Observa que en todo momento hasta ahora he usado "vinculado a" o "hacer referencia a" y no he dicho nada de punteros. Primero porque en Python no existen los punteros, pero también porque, una cosa es Python como lenguaje/especificación y otra las implementaciones del mismo. La implementación oficial de Python esta hecha en lenguaje C y se conoce como CPython, pero existen otras que se implementan también en C o en otros lenguajes como Java, C# o Rust.

Python (como lenguaje) especifica que es, como se define y como se debe comportar una variable, pero no especifica como se vincula ese nombre con el objeto en memoria al que hace referencia, eso depende de la implementación. En el caso de CPython por debajo hay, sorpresa, punteros de tipo `PyObject*`, pero en otras implementaciones no tiene porque hacerse uso de punteros para vincular un nombre con su objeto, incluso puede que los punteros no existan como tal en el lenguaje usado en esa implementación.

CPython es la implementación mas usada con diferencia, por lo que se suele asumir que Python == CPython en muchos contextos, en lo que resta de respuesta lo voy ha hacer así también, pero siempre tener esto presente.

### Variables en Python y en C

A grandes rasgos, en C una variable es una ubicación de memoria con un nombre. El valor de la variable es por tanto el valor almacenado en esa ubicación y asignar a la variable es modificar ese valor. La variable es la posición de memoria en si, no su nombre, y tiene un tipo fijo.

Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinamico que usa *duck typing*, una variable es un nombre utilizado para referirse a un objeto, hay que entender que la variable es una cosa y el objeto es otra distinta y "viven" por separado. Asignar a la variable no modifica el objeto en sí, solo cambia el objeto al que se refiere (esta vinculada) esa variable. Una variable no tiene realmente un tipo, el tipo, el valor y la localización en memoria pertenecen al objeto no a la variable.

Se puede decir que en Python no existen realmente las variables, lo que hay son nombres/identifiacadores. Estos nombres pertenecen a un ámbito concreto, siempre harán referencia a un objeto en memoria y se les puede vincular con cualquier otro objeto de cualquier tipo en el momento que queramos.

### ¿Son entonces las variables punteros?

Es lógico pensar que las variables en Python actúan como los punteros en C, salvando las distancias, algo como lo que ocurre en:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Carro {
    char marca[100];
};

int main(){
    struct Carro carro;
    
    struct Carro *nuevo_carro = &carro;
    strcpy(nuevo_carro->marca, "Honda");
    
    struct Carro *otro = nuevo_carro;
    strcpy(otro->marca, "Subaru");
    
    printf("%s\n", otro->marca);        // Subaru
    printf("%s\n", nuevo_carro->marca); // Subaru 

    return 0;
}
```

Pero realmente no, los nombres/identificadores en CPython en esencia usan punteros de tipo `PyObject*` por debajo para vincular el identificador con un objeto en memoria, actúan como punteros con referencia y desreferencia automáticas, pero no son punteros como los entendemos en C, por ejemplo no permiten operaciones de punteros de forma directa. Es mas, en otras implementaciones de Python puede no haber siquiera punteros implicados.

### ¿Que esta pasando en tu código entonces?

Todo objeto en CPython a nivel de C esta representado por `PyObject` (un struct de C) que esta definido por tres cosas; su tipo, su valor y un conteo de referencias al mismo.

Cuando haces:

```
primer_carro = Carro()
```

pasan muchas cosas por debajo:

1. Se crea un `PyObject`
2. Se establece el typecode de ese `PyObject` a `Carro`
3. Se establece el valor al de tu instancia concreta y se almacena en memoria.
4. Se crea un nombre `primer_carro` en el espacio de nombres (ámbito) en el que este esa expresión.
5. Se vincula el nombre `primer_carro` al nuevo `PyObject`.
6. Por ultimo se incrementa el refcount del nuevo  `PyObject` en 1

Cuando haces después:

```
otro = primer_carro
```

Lo único que ocurre es que:

1. Se crea un nombre `otro` en el espacio de nombres.
2. Se vincula el nombre `otro` al PyObject al que esta vinculado el nombre `primer_carro`
3. Se incrementa el conteo de referencias del PyObject en uno. Ahora hay dos nombres haciendo referencia al mismo objeto en memoria.

En ningún momento se ha copiado o modificado el objeto original.

**Observa que las variables en ningún momento tienen en propiedad la memoria en la que el objeto esta alojado, es el PyObject el que la tiene. La variable simplemente esta vinculada a el**. Ambas variables hacen referencia al mismo objeto y por tanto, cuando modificas el objeto usando uno de los nombres vinculados al mismo, el cambio se ve también al acceder al objeto con el otro identificador, son el mismo objeto...

Esto es muy diferente a lo que ocurre en C, donde esperarías que se copiara el valor de la variable.

---

Podemos hacer un simil de lo que es una "variable" en Python en la vida real, imagina que te llamas *José Manuel*, pero es posible que alguna gente te llame también *Pepe* u otra *Josema*, la realidad es que todos en un ámbito/contexto concreto son solo nombres que te identifican a ti y que sirven para comunicarse contigo. Da igual que alguien diga *Josema.pásame_la_sal()* o *Pepe.pásame_la_sal()*, los nombres no son mas que una forma de referirse a ti y comunicarse contigo o pedirte que hagas algo. Tu existes independientemente de esos nombres, incluso puedes ir al registro civil y cambiarte el nombre por *Guido*..., ahora ya *Jose Manuel* no te identificaría a ti, tendrían que llamarte con *Guido.pasame_la_sal()* pero tu no has cambiado, solo se usa otro nombre para identificarte.

Entender esto es muy importante, por ejemplo, en el caso de objetos mutables:

```
>>> a = [3, 4]
>>> b = a # a y b identifican al mismo objeto list en memoria, la lista no se copia

>>> b[0] = 7
>>> a
[7, 4]
```

Si quieres copiar la lista debes usar `copy.copy`, la sintaxis del rebanado de listas `b = a[::]` o el método `list.copy()` (las tres crean una una copia superficial) o `copy.deepcopy` para una copia profunda.

O a la hora de entender como funciona el manejo automático de memoria en Python:

```
import gc
import weakref

class Carro():
    pass

nuevo_carro = Carro()
print(nuevo_carro) # <__main__.Carro object at 0x7fb983f1e720>

otro = nuevo_carro
print(otro)        # <__main__.Carro object at 0x7fb983f1e720>
print(nuevo_carro is otro) # True

wref = weakref.ref(nuevo_carro)
del(nuevo_carro)
gc.collect() # Forzamos un ciclo de recoleccion de basura
print(otro) # <__main__.Carro object at 0x7fb983f1e720>
print(wref) # <weakref at 0x7fb9840b2f70; to 'Carro' at 0x7fb983f1e720>

del(otro)
gc.collect()
print(wref) # <weakref at 0x7fb9840b2f70; dead>
```

Como podemos ver tanto `nuevo_carro` como `otro` referencian el mismo objeto en memoria. `weakref.ref` crea una referencia débil al objeto, es decir, no incrementa el contador de referencias del mismo, por lo que el recolector de basura no la tendrá en cuenta a la hora de decidir si debe eliminar el objeto de la memoria (contador de referencias en cero).

`del(variable)` elimina la variable del ámbito, no el objeto al que esta asociada, ya que este es independiente de la variable. Al eliminar el nombre, el contador de referencias del objeto simplemente decrece en uno, pero el objeto no es recolectado mientras exista al menos una referencia a el. En este caso al eliminar ambas variables el recolector de basura lo eliminara en el siguiente ciclo de limpieza, y como vemos en el ultimo `print`, el objeto ya no existe (weakref dead).

---

### Edición

En lo referente al comentario:

> ¿Pero por que ese comportamiento no funciona igual cuando creo
> variables "simples"? Es decir:
>
> ```
> a = 3
> b = a
> b = 2
> ```
>
> en este caso el valor de a sigue siendo 3 en lugar de 2

Ten en cuenta que:

```
a = 3
b = a
b = 2
```

No es lo mismo que:

```
a = Carro()
a.marca = "Honda"
b = a
b.marca = "Subaru"
```

aquí **estas asignando un nuevo objeto al atributo `marca` del objeto referenciado por `b`**, no le estas asignando un nuevo objeto a `b` en si misma, que seria:

```
a = Carro()
a.marca = "Honda"
b = Carro()
b.marca = "Subaru"
```

El atributo `marca` en esencia es también un identificador/nombre que pertenece al ámbito de la instancia. Cuando haces `b.marca = "Subaru"` estas vinculando un nuevo objeto `str` al identificador `marca` de la instancia a la que hace referencia `b`, que es la misma instancia a la que hace referencia `a`, eso no cambia. Tal vez sea mas facil de entender con un esquema (puedes leer las flechas como "hace referencia a"):

```
a = 3
b = a
```

> ```
> ╔═══╗      ╔═════════════════════╗
> | a |════> |Objeto int(3)        |
> ╚═══╝ ╔══> | id: 0x7f61dca77b101 |
>       ║    | refcount: 2         |
> ╔═══╗ ║    ╚═════════════════════╝
> | b |═╝
> ╚═══╝
> ```

```
b = 2
```

> ```
> ╔═══╗      ╔═════════════════════╗
> | a |════> | Objeto int(3)       |
> ╚═══╝      |  id: 0x7f61dca77b101|
>            |  refcount: 1        |
> ╔═══╗      ╚═════════════════════╝
> | b |═╗
> ╚═══╝ ║    ╔═════════════════════╗
>       ╚══> | Objeto int(2)       |
>            |  id: 0x7c41fc452b123|
>            |  refcount: 1        |
>            ╚═════════════════════╝
> ```

```
nuevo_carro = Carro()
nuevo_carro.marca = "Honda"
otro = nuevo_carro
```

> ```
> ╔═══════════╗      ╔═════════════════════╗      ╔═════════════════════╗
> |nuevo_carro|═════>| Objeto Carro        |  ╔═> | Objeto str("Honda") |
> ╚═══════════╝ ╔═══>|  id: 0x7f61dca77b101|  ║   |  id: 0x7f61dca42a743|
>               ║    |  refcount: 2        |  ║   |  refcount: 1        |
> ╔═══════════╗ ║    |---------------------|  ║   ╚═════════════════════╝
> |   otro    |═╝    |   marca             |══╝ 
> ╚═══════════╝      ╚═════════════════════╝
> ```

```
otro.marca = "Subaru"
```

> ```
> ╔═══════════╗      ╔═════════════════════╗      ╔═════════════════════╗
> |nuevo_carro|═════>| Objeto Carro        |      | Objeto str("Honda") |
> ╚═══════════╝ ╔═══>|  id: 0x7f61dca77b101|      |  id: 0x7f61dca42a743|
>               ║    |  refcount: 2        |      |  refcount: 0        |
> ╔═══════════╗ ║    |---------------------|      ╚═════════════════════╝
> |   otro    |═╝    |   marca             |═╗ 
> ╚═══════════╝      ╚═════════════════════╝ ║    ╔═════════════════════╗
>                                            ╚══> | Objeto str("Subaru")|
>                                                 |  id: 0x5c74cd245a204|
>                                                 |  refcount: 1        |
>                                                 ╚═════════════════════╝
> ```

Otra confusión común es no distinguir entre reasignar un nuevo objeto a una variable y modificar el objeto en si mismo usando una variable que hace referencia al mismo. Lo cual esta intimamente relacionado con el concepto de mutabilidad:

```
>>> a = "Hola"
>>> id(a)
140608073840688     # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> a += " mundo"            
>>> a                      
'Hola mundo'               
>>> id(a)                  
140608072449964     # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Aunque el operador += generalmente actua in-place, aquí no ha modificado el objeto `str` asociado a `a`, sino que ha generado  un nuevo objeto `str` resultado de concatenar dos objetos `str` y ese nuevo objeto lo hemos reasignado a la variable `a`. Esto pasa porque es imposible modificar un objeto `str` porque es inmutable, igual que `int`, `float` o `tuple`.

Esto es diferente a modificar un objeto mutable o sus atributos usando una variable que hace referencia al mismo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
140608072870976      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> a += [4, 5]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> id(a)
140608072870976      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

En este caso no ha habido reasignacion, `list` es un objeto mutable y el operador `+=` en este caso si puede actuar in-place sin crear un nuevo objeto como hace en el caso de `str` (similar a usar `a.extend([4, 5])`).

Caso distinto es que hagamos:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
140608072870976      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> a = a + [4, 5]
>>> id(a)
140608072875241      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Donde si estamos asociando un nuevo objeto `list` dado que el operador `+` no actua in-place.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, ya me quedo claro entonces que lo que estaba haciendo era creando solo una referencia más para un mimso objeto ¿Pero por que ese comportamiento no funciona igual cuando creo variables "simples"? Es decir  '''a = 3    b = a    b = 2 '''  en este caso el valor de a sigue siendo 3 en lugar de 2

Comment: Hola Victor, funciona igual, lo que pasa es que en el ejemplo de tu pregunta no reasignas a las variables como haces en el comentario, sino al atributo `marca` del objeto que **ambas referencian**.  He editado la respuesta, mira al final de la misma a ver si he conseguido explicarlo.

Comment: Okay, ya entiendo, se puede decir que cuando hago ''' b = 2 ''' estoy es instanceando un nuevo objeto b de clase int, es decir, que ya como explicaste en el esquema b ya no hace referencia al mismo objeto que a, sino a uno nuevo (o asi fue como lo interprete) . Nuevamente muchas gracias por responder, de verdad  ¿Podrias recomendarme alguna fuente para poder aprender estos temas, o todo se encuentra en la documentacion de Python?

Comment: Si, `b = 2` instancia un nuevo objeto de la clase `int` (mas explícitamente sin el literal seria `b = int(2)`) y a continuación se hace que el nombre (variable) `b` haga referencia a ese nuevo objeto creado, por lo que deja de estar vinculado al anterior objeto (al que si sigue asociada `a`).  Lo que cambia es que `b` pasa a hacer referencia a otro objeto `int` diferente en memoria. Igual que al hacer `otro.marca = "Subaru"` *el atributo `marca`* del objeto asociado a `otro` pasa a hacer referencia a un nuevo objeto `str` en memoria.

Comment: Lo anterior no es estrictamente cierto en el caso de los enteros pequeños (de -5 a 256) en CPython ya que el interprete tiene estos objetos preinstanciados almacenados, de forma que `b = 3` en vez de crear un nuevo objeto int simplemente vincula `b` con una instancia de `int(3)` preexistente, lo mismo pasa con `None` (singleton), `False` o `True`. Esto se hace por eficiencia dado que son objetos comúnmente usados e inmutables, pero es un detalle de implementación de CPython, ignóralo si te confunde, la idea general es lo comentado antes.

Comment: En cuanto a fuentes, la documentación oficial de Python es bastante  buena y siempre debe ser el punto de referencia. Obviamente no todas las cuestiones concretas que te plantees van a tener una entrada propia en la documentación, puede que se de respuesta en ella pero de forma dispersa en varias partes, hay cosas de mi respuesta explicadas en https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model, en https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers o https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html?highlight=names#naming-and-binding

Comment: Aparte de eso, si algo tiene python es una comunidad enorme, tienes tutoriales y fuentes de información a raudales en internet, especialmente si el ingles no es un problema, incluido por supuesto [es.so] y [so].  Para ciertas dudas pueden ser mejor opción que la documentación porque, aunque esa información este en ella a veces no es fácil de encontrar, esta dispersa o se requiere un conocimiento mas profundo. En este tema concreto buscando un poco, creo que el tutorial de https://realpython.com/python-variables/ es también un buen punto de entrada para entender las variables en Python.

Answer (score 1):

> Como si fuesen la misma instancia pero con distintos nombres

No puedo decir si actúa o no como apuntadores, ya que no conozco C, pero...

Exactamente eso sucede. Las variables en Python son "nombres que le das a un objeto". Y en tu código le estás dando otro nombre a la misma instancia.

Cuando accedes a una variable, en realidad accedes a una id con la que se puede obtener el valor en cuestión. La función built-in id puede usarse para obtener dicha id.

Cuando se habla de que una variable señala a un objeto, se dice que la variable **referencia** al objeto (esa palabra es clave para tus búsquedas sobre el tema)

De hecho podés hacer `id(primer_carro) == id(otro)` y te dará True. Esta comparación resulta en lo mismo que `primer_carro is otro`. El operador is indica si dos variables referencian a lo mismo, NO si son iguales.

##### Por que debe entenderse bien

Te recomiendo entender bien el funcionamiento de las variables en Python. Te ayudará a evitar errores derivados del desconocimiento. Como por ejemplo intentar copiar una lista:

(NUNCA hagas esto en tu código)

```
a = b = []
```

En donde a y b referencian a la misma lista, por lo que modificar a afecta a b.

---

Para mi sorpresa, tampoco encontré mucha mención de esto echando una mirada rápida a la documentación.

(**Edit** estas palabras claves no tuvieron efecto) Te invito a buscar en internet ahora buscando usando las palabras "variable" y "referencia"

Links relevantes:

[¿Es igual "import XXX" que "from XXX import a, b, c"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/510310/158880)

[¿Por qué un método recursivo en Python no toma el valor por defecto de un parámetro en segundas llamadas, sino que conserva su valor previo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/591689/158880)